# Boot Class Path extension support for OSGi kf framework

Tags: java, osgi, knopflerfish

Is Boot Class Path extension supported in kf framework? If it is supported, how can I configure to set the property to always be true?

I've tried setting org.osgi.supports.bootclasspath.extension property to true but to no avail.

From the extracted code below (taken from FWProps.java, initProperties method), it seems that the property will always be set to false unless it's not the first framework which contradicts with the comment found in the code.

```
// Only first framework can support bootclasspath extension 
// NYI! Improve this in the future 
if(getBooleanProperty(Constants.SUPPORTS_BOOTCLASSPATH_EXTENSION) &&
   !(getClass().getClassLoader() instanceof URLClassLoader && fwCtx.id == 1))
{
    props.put(Constants.SUPPORTS_BOOTCLASSPATH_EXTENSION, FALSE); }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set that property. That property is the framework telling you that it support bootclasspath extension. Most of the commonly available framework don't support it because it requires special coding to integrate with the JVM. Setting the bootclasspath is not a standard option on JVMs as well as how to restart the JVM to make the change take effect. So it requires a framework implementation to be customized for a specific JVM and perhaps deployment.